# Move CAGradient layer to background in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

I have created a gradient using a CAGradient object. However, once I call the function to create the gradient layer, it apparently ends up on top, as none of my other objects in the view controller show up.

```
func createGradientLayer() {
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
    gradientLayer.colors = [colorOne, colorTwo]
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
```

I then called it in viewDidLoad()

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    createGradientLayer()
}
```

How can I get my view controller objects to show up again? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use below line:

```
self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
```

instead of `self.view.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)`

Comment: You are welcome, please make my answer as a correct answer 